# How to Compare 2 Dates and subtract 1 second if it's true

Tags: javascript

I want to Compare The date which is manually inputted by the user to the Specific date which is 12:00AM, after that i want to subtract 1 second on the 1st date

```
var d1 = $('#d1').val();
var d11 = new Date(d1);
var d12 = new Date();
d12.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   if(d11.getTime() === d12.getTime()){
       var seconds = d11.getSeconds() - 1;
       d11 = d11 - seconds;
   }
```

I expect output is 23:59:59 but the actual input is error

Comment: `d11.setSeconds(d11.getSeconds() -1)`? though, not sure why subtracting one second from a given date would give `23:59:00` as the time - it'd be `23:59:59`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in several ways. But not the way you tried. Issue is you can
not perform integer operations on Date type as you have tried here.

You can go along something similar to below.

```
var t = new Date();
t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() - 1);
```

or

```
new Date(Date.now() - 1000);
```

here 1000 is in milliseconds.